# Question about feasibility of fantasy weapons

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it off topic to ask whether certain weapons common to fantasy RPGs (e.g. battleaxes with extremely large blades) would make feasible real-world weapons?

Comment: Did you ever end up asking a question about this?...

Comment: @Sardathrion nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fantasy weapon has a *grounding in real life*, then I suspect it would be on topic.

So, asking if a [buster sword](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Buster_Sword) is practical would be off topic as it is a fantasy weapon with no grounding in real life whatsoever. However, asking if a "large battle axe" could be used as a [Fu](http://www.chinawhisper.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/fu.jpg) would be on topic. Or even what martial art uses "large battles axes".

Weapon identification is on topic if it is a real weapon.  A question speculating on the origin of a fantasy weapon might be best asked on [scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).

Some fantasy weapons do look no stranger than real life ones...

[image: Blade of the Immortals]

[image: Chinese martial art weapons]

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

In general I think your proposed question would be a bad fit on the site because it would lead to speculation, guesswork, opinion and extended discussion - all things that are good on a forum but not on a Q&A site.

The thing to remember is that the question's subject matter is fantasy, therefore a lot of real world rules don't apply.

But in case you're wondering, the simplest way to answer your question is to consider current history - do any of the established weapons match the hypothetical battle axe with a large blade? If not then it's because it wasn't a good feasible real world weapon  - it's not because the warriors of centuries gone didn't think of it.